# C# внешнее отображение полей класса

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Вчера в голову пришла интересная мысль. Допустим, у нас есть класс `someObject`:

```
class someObject
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

И также допустим, что у нас есть `comboBox`, который нам нужно заполнить этими самыми `someObject`, которые лежат в каком-то листе, т.е. сделать так:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
   comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Если сделать это так, то в `comboBox` будет что-то подобное на каждый элемент:

```
Form+someObject
```

Хорошо, пойдём другой дорогой. Будем заполнять вот так:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(item.name);
}
```

Теперь в `comboBox`'е будет отображаться имя элемента `name`. Теперь после выбора какого-либо элемента из `comboBox` для получения конкретного элемента листа, нужно будет делать вот так:

```
someObject currentItem;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(item.name == comboBox.Text)
    {
        currentItem = item;
    }
}
```

Хорошо. Всё это работает. Но есть одно "но": если в листе есть объекты с одинаковыми именами, то после тех же манипуляций, которые описаны выше, мы не всегда будем получать именно тот объект, который нам нужен. Я хочу сказать, что цикл `foreach` пройдётся по всему листу, сверит имя каждого элемента с `comboBox.Text` и будет сохранять в переменную последнее проверенное значение.

А если сделать вот так:

```
someObject currentItem;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(item.name == comboBox.Text)
    {
        currentItem = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

то будет сохраняться только первое значение.

Так вот, к чему я всё это: Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты, чтобы при добавлении элемента вот так

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
   comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

в `comboBox` отображалось только имя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто задайте свойство

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Можно использовать конструкцию

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(someObject.name);
```

Однако, при этом нужно заменить поля на свойства:

```
class someObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

А также желательно использовать PascalCase для публичных свойств: `Id`, `Name` и имён класса: `SomeObject`.

Примечание: также обратите внимание на свойство `ValueMember` комбобокса.

Comment: Насчёт PascalCase, я ипровизировал. Нужно было донести основную суть вопроса. Но спасибо за указание на ошибку.